# Rolling a die probability given the history

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Suppose that I rolled a die once and got 3. I rolled it second time and got 4.

Is it true, that probability of getting 5 on third roll, given two previous attempts is not $\frac{1}{6}$? It should be higher (empirical probability). How can I calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

[If your die is fair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice), then each outcome is equally likely, and the die has no memory. Therefore, the probability of future outcomes does not depend on previous outcomes. A 5 on the third roll is no more or less probable after rolling 3 and 4 than after rolling 1 and 6, or after rolling a hundred times 5 in a row (which, by itself, would indeed be very unlikely - but would not have any influence on the one hundred and first roll).

Of course, this does not hold if your dice are loaded.

Misunderstanding this is known as [the gambler's fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy).

Comment: There's a bit of ambiguity here: Exactly what part of "this" does not hold for loaded dice?  Lack of memory?